# SQL Query Question (Possible Join / Subquery?)

Tags: sql, oracle, join, subquery, ora-00937

I have two tables (**Management** and **Employee**).

The management table tracks the different management teams that have managed company X in past few years. Each management team is given an ID (i.e: managementnr), and each team has a CEO (namely ceoname).

The employee table tracks employees working for company X (basically just their names and which management team hired them)

Here is the SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE(
    EMPLOYEENAME   VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
    HIRETEAM NUMBER(2), 
    PRIMARY KEY (EMPLOYEENAME)
    );

CREATE TABLE MANAGEMENT(
    MANAGEMENTNR NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
    CEONAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (MANAGEMENTNR,CEONAME)
    );
```

I'm trying to form an SQL query to get the managementNR in which the highest number of employees have been hired. 
I've tried using:

```
SELECT HIRETEAM,max(count(HIRETEAM)) 
 from EMPLOYEE 
group by HIRETEAM
```

but I keep getting:

```
  ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
```

(I'm using Oracle)

After hours of Google-fu, I finally understand what this error means, however I still cannot think of any other way to form this query. I've tried using subqueries / joins, but  still nothing. I'm very new to SQL in general. If anybody can help, I would be really grateful!

Thank you for your time =]
--Evan Lestrange

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for this:

```
WITH counts_hireteam as (
   SELECT HIRETEAM
        , count(*) count_hireteam
     from EMPLOYEE 
   group by HIRETEAM
   order by count(*) desc
) 
select HIRETEAM  
  from counts_hireteam
 where rownum = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Get the first row from this query:

```
select hireteam,count(*) from EMPLOYEE group by hireteam order by count(*) desc
```

Answer (score 2):

The "correct" way to do this is actually something like:

```
SELECT m.ceoname, COUNT(1), ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC)
FROM management m
JOIN employee e ON m.managementnr = e.hireteam
GROUP BY m.ceoname
```

You're getting into the murkky area of Top-N queries and I'll direct you to this [excellent column of Ask Tom on Top-N](http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/oracle/07-jan/o17asktom.html). Other answers work in simple cases but it's when you start wanting to do things like returning the top 3 management teams (by head count) and doing so consistently that you'll run into problems.

Consistency is a key point. As Tom notes:

> Does a GROUP BY clause in a query
>   guarantee that the output data will be
>   sorted on the GROUP BY columns in
>   order, even if there is no ORDER BY
>   clause?
>
> Unless and until there is an ORDER BY
>   statement on a query, the rows
>   returned cannot be assumed to be in
>   any order. Without an ORDER BY, the
>   data may be returned in any order in
>   which the database feels like
>   returning it. This has always been
>   true and will always be true.
>
> In fact, in Oracle Database 10g
>   Release 2, you'll see GROUP BY
>   returning data in a random order much
>   more often than before:

Using this sample data:

```
INSERT INTO employee VALUES ('Bob',1);
INSERT INTO employee VALUES ('Sue',1);
INSERT INTO employee VALUES ('John',1);
INSERT INTO employee VALUES ('James',2);
INSERT INTO employee VALUES ('Mary',2);
INSERT INTO employee VALUES ('Ron', 2);
INSERT INTO employee VALUES ('Jane',3);
INSERT INTO employee VALUES ('Luke',4);
INSERT INTO employee VALUES ('Rob',4);
INSERT INTO employee VALUES ('Tim', 5);

INSERT INTO management VALUES (1, 'Kate');
INSERT INTO management VALUES (2, 'Larry');
INSERT INTO management VALUES (3, 'Jake');
INSERT INTO management VALUES (4, 'Sarah');
INSERT INTO management VALUES (5, 'Tom');
```

Answer (score 0):

This way you get all teams with the number of hired employees.

```
select
    Management.ManagementNr,
    Management.CeoName,
    count(Employee.EmployeeName)   
from 
    Employee 
inner join 
    Management on Employee.HireTeam = Management.ManagementNr   
group by 
    Management.ManagementNr   
order by 
    count(Employee.EmployeeName) desc
```

Adding a additional having clause and abandoning the join (because the CEO name is not required as I just recognized) you get your desired result as follows.

```
select Employee.HireTeam   
from Employee   
group by Employee.HireTeam   
having count(EmployeeName) = select max(GroupSize)
   from select count(EmployeeName) as GroupSize
      from Employee group by Employee.HireTeam
```

This may actually return multiple rows if several management hired the same number of employees. And it is ugly ... but ad hoc I know no better way to do it in a single query.

Comment: I just copied the naming convention ... and abdonned it quickly ... :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit the results to a single record, even in the case of ties for the greatest number of hires:

```
select * from (
    select hireteam, count(hireteam) count
    from employee
    group by hireteam
    order by count(hireteam) desc, hireteam asc )
where rownum = 1
```

To retrieve all hireteam values having the most hires (including ties):

```
select * from (
    select hireteam,
           count(hireteam) count,
           rank() over (order by count(hireteam) desc) rank
    from   employee
    group by hireteam)
where rank = 1;
```